# Count Delimiter in a string in Java

Tags: java

i have a string in Java.

```
1|2|3|4|5|2|2|3|4|123441|234556|67783|56764|55454
```

i want **to count a delimiter above string**. Please help me in how to count and i want only starting 7 Delimiter value.

Comment: split using `|` and take the first 7 values? What's your expected output? 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 2 + 2?

Comment: my expected result is  1|2|3|4|5|2|2|

Comment: What is your pattern exactly?

Comment: i want to parse this string  1|43|20150608|579037|1234567890123||000|||||MR HEELO WORLD||||||||0234567890|||||||||H NO 13 SOMWEHERE IN THE WORLD    |||||      and only waht i want is below string 1|43|20150608|579037|1234567890123||000|

Answer (score 1):

You can split using `|` character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1|2|3|4|5|2|2|3|4|123441|234556|67783|56764|55454";
    String[] strArr = s.split("\\|");
    System.out.println("Array : " + Arrays.toString(strArr));
    System.out.println("Delimiter count : " + (strArr.length - 1)); // Prints 13
    System.out.println("7th field : " + strArr[7]); // Prints 3
}
```

Comment: The approach is fine, but it doesn't result in the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with regular expressions, using Pattern and Matcher classes:

```
    String s = "1|2|3|4|5|2|2|3|4|123441|234556|67783|56764|55454";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\d+\\|){7}).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

To understand the code above, have a look at regular expressions, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case if your input string if sthg like this:-

```
1|2|3|4|5|2|2|3|4|123441|234556|||
```

having empty values between delimiters. Then you can go with a different version of `split` function.

```
String[] strArr = s.split("\\|", -1);
```

You need to pass -1 as the second argument to split otherwise it removes empty strings.